# How to hide certificate password in saml.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, passwords, hide

I've been researching ways to hide the password that I presently have hardcoded in my saml.config file. While I can find a lot of documentation on how to hide a password in the web.config file, I can't find anything on hiding passwords in other config files.

The closest I have found is using Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders and using a feature similar to ASP.NET Core Secret Manager called the UserSecretsConfigBuilder.

While this looks like a good candidate, it uses key/value pairs in the  section of, you guessed it, web.config. I was thinking well, maybe I can store the password placeholder here, get it on application startup, get the actual password in the code behind using ConfigurationManager.AppSettings and then at runtime, write the actual password to the saml.config file before initiating the SAML based SSO. That doesn't seem to be the best way to do this. Anyone know a better way?

I'm using ASP.NET and C# code-behind, .NET Framework 4.8 and the application is a WebForms based application, so no, not using .NET Core or MVC.

Thanks!